# Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
INSERT INTO [Temp].[dbo].[Student]
    ([Fname], [Lname], [Gender])
    VALUES 
    (N'Aname', N'Alname', N'Male')
    GO
```

This codes workes fine but when I try to add multiple values it gives me an error

> Error: Incorrect syntax near ','.

```
USE TEMP
GO

INSERT INTO [Temp].[dbo].[Student]
([Fname], [Lname], [Gender])
VALUES 
(N'Aname', N'Alname', N'Male'),
(N'Bname', N'Blname', N'Male')
GO
```

Comment: Are you sure you've keyed in the query exactly as you're using it? It works fine on my machine... Or are you running against a SQL2005 instance

Comment: Are you sure you're running on SQL Server 2008? What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return?

Comment: If you are running on 2008, check the compatibly setting for the instance.

Comment: @BrianDishaw no, compatibility level (which is at the database level, not instance level) does not affect the ability to use this syntax. I think the OP thinks they're running against SQL Server 2008, but they aren't.

Comment: Im using Sql Server 2008 
SELECT @@VERSION returns Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86)   Feb  9 2007 22:47:07   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: As others have commented - the SQL statement itself is fine, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25a50/1/0

Comment: `9.00` is SQL Server 2005. It even says `SQL Server 2005` in what you posted.

Comment: You might be running SQL Server Management Studio **2008** - but the output from your `SELECT @@VERSION` clearly says: `Microsoft SQL Server **2005** ` and that version doesn't support this insert syntax yet

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the clarification. I didn't realize compat modes were there for partial backwards compatibility.

Comment: @BrianDishaw yes, they can have effect on some syntax, but not this specific case.

Comment: Thanks for help. I think I understand the point but my login page show that it is sql server 2008 http://s17.postimage.org/rcycm5ggv/image.jpg but SELECT @@VERSION returns 2005 how can I fix this inconsistency?

Comment: @Ebeen that is not your login page, that is just the version of the client tool you have installed on your machine. It does not need to be the same as the servers you manage (after all, how would that work if you have to manage a 2000, 2005 and 2008 instance?), but it should be >= the highest version you have to manage. You can use the 2005 version if you want to be "consistent" but I fail to see why you would want to do that. If you want to use SQL Server 2008+ syntax, the "fix" is to upgrade the *server* to 2008+, not make the client tool the same version as the server.

Comment: Closed as too localised? Really??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to use the multi-row `VALUES(),()` syntax, you need to be running SQL Server 2008 (or newer).

Since you are running SQL Server 2005, you need to run separate insert statements, use UNION/UNION ALL, or upgrade the instance (which is separate from Management Studio, which is just a client tool you use to connect to instances running any number of versions of SQL Server).

Comment: Can you provide the syntax for this?

Comment: I'd also like the syntax for this please

Answer (score 7):

You can do it this way:

```
insert into [Temp].[dbo].[Student]
select 'Aname', 'Alname', 'AMale'
union all
select 'Bname', 'BAlname', 'BMale'
```

etc etc

Thanks

Paul.

Comment: Why was it marked down?  It's a working and correct solution.  To insert multiple rows use select.

Comment: But the problem isn't the syntax, for anyone running SQL Server 2008 `VALUES` is typically preferred over `UNION`. The problem is the OP isn't on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: yeah I gathered that, so instead of stalling your development because a functionality isn't available, use the legacy method of doing it.

Comment: This is valuable.  Thanks, @PaulG.  As we move legacy systems to the cloud, we're going to be touching previously undisturbed data. This question and its answer(s) were helpful and a reminder about db capability.