# Data Saves in EF7 with One Object - Not With Many

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a an object model in EF7 that looks something like this:

```
Story -> StoryPhotos[]
```

I build the model through a form submission of a story where a user may also attach N number of photos. The model creation looks something like this:

```
var story = new Story
{
  // ...

  StoryPhotos = myFormData.Photos.Select(p => new StoryPhoto {
    Name = p.Name,
    FileName = p.FileName,
    etc.
  }).ToList()
}
```

Then, once I have built my data models, I save the data via a repository.

```
await repository.AddOrUpdateStoryAsync(story)
```

which looks like this

```
if (story.Id == 0)
{
    context.Stories.Add(story);
    context.StoryPhotos.AddRange(story.StoryPhotos);
}
else
{
  // Update properties for an edit.
}
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This works great...as long as I only have a single StoryPhoto. As soon as I put more than one into the array, I get this exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ','.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__17(Task`1 result)
```

My research shows that there have been a few different issues with regards to how EF7 is saving object graphs, but I am confused in the case where one saves fine and more than one doesn't, with no other changes to the code.

I am using EntityFramework-SqlServer 7.0.0-beta7.

Comment: When dealing with an ORM, SQL syntax exception is definitely a bug

Comment: @haim770 I was wondering (esp considering the beta status). But, of course, history has taught me that I shouldn't blame the library first. I'll check the source on Github tomorrow as another avenue. I'll leave the question in case someone can give me another idea.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you have. Now that EF 7 beta 8 is released, you could try upgrading to that to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: @htuomola - Yeah, I was going to do that when I got a moment to upgrade my project. I did find a workaround, but, it is definitely a workaround which is why I hadn't posted it as an answer yet. I'll keep the update here if beta8 fixes it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is the answer. I also posted it in [response to the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3691#issuecomment-158663557) (which is not an issue) being tracked on the ASP.NET 5 Entity Framework GitHub. Repeating here for anybody who runs into it as well.

Okay, I am able to recreate the issue directly on my SQL database. Here is the query that is being generated.

```
INSERT INTO [StoryPhoto] ([FilePath], [StoryId])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
      VALUES ('path1', '174'),
      ('path2', '174'),
      ('path3', '174');
```

And I get this error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

In addition, being able to find this, I Googled my original question a bit differently (when I first ran across this) and found [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296739/incorrect-syntax-near) which included this answer:

> In order to use the multi-row VALUES(),() syntax, you need to be 
>   running SQL Server 2008 (or newer).
>
> Since you are running SQL Server 2005, you need to run  separate
>   insert statements, use UNION/UNION ALL, or upgrade  the instance
>   (which is separate from Management Studio, which  is just a client
>   tool you use to connect to instances running any  number of versions
>   of SQL Server).

So, it was my suspicion in my original post. This particular application is still running SQL Server 2005.

This led me to find the database versions that EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer support which is 2008 and greater.